# Six LED Strips 24 V with battery - runtime?

Tags: batteries, led, calculation

I bought six 250 cm long addressable 24 V LED flexible tubes from Sunliteleds.com

According to the producer it uses 28.8 W/m

2.5 meters x 28.8 W = **72 W / Strip**

So if I use a battery with 10.4 Ah at 24 V = 249.56 Wh

I get 249.56 / 72 = **3.47 h runtime** for one LED strip.

Is my calculation correct? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Your circuit has no voltage regulation then the LEDs will slowly get dimmer as the battery voltage runs down. During the 3.47V time, the battery voltage might drop below the minimum voltage for the LEDs to produce light, reducing the lighted time.

Comment: Thanks - I will add at 24V voltage regulator